# Python reads only last line in text file

Tags: python, paramiko, cisco

I am trying to read 2 IP address from text file and connect these devices and run the "conf t" command on these devices. When i trying to do this job by following coding, python reads only last line in text file, not reading the first line. What should i do? Thanks.

```
import paramiko

username = "xxxx"
password = "yyyy"

f = open("C:\\Users\0\Desktop\\deneme.txt")

for line in f:
  ip_address = line.strip()
  ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address, username=username, password=password)

f.close()

print ("Successfull", ip_address)

remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()

remote_connection.send("conf t\n")
```

Comment: What happens if you do readlines?

Comment: No, it reads all the lines, you just keep overwriting the values you assign in your `for` loop so that when you break out of the loop, all you're left with is the last values.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you wish to do that ?

```
import paramiko

username = "xxxx"
password = "yyyy"

f = open("C:\\Users\0\Desktop\\deneme.txt")

for line in f:
  ip_address = line.strip()
  ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address, username=username, password=password)
  print ("Successfull", ip_address)
  remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
  remote_connection.send("conf t\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: Oh it works now. Sorry , i am newbie to Python. Thanks a lot :)